# How to deny access to a file using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I need to block access to a particular file (containing private data) in a directory using .htaccess. Is this possible?

We use Apache and nginx.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to prevent viewing of a specific file, for example picture.jpg:

```
<files picture.jpg>
     order allow,deny
     deny from all
</files>
```

change picture.jpg with your file.

If you want to deny access to all files with .jpg extension:

```
<files  ~ "\.jpg$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files "yourfile">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Files>
```

See [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) for more info...